# how to detect when an empty directory is uploaded in chrome angular

Tags: html, angular, file-upload

I have a angular application in which I can upload directories containing files.
Issue: I cannot detect when a directory is selected that is completely empty. The selectFile($event) function is not getting triggered.

uploaddata.component.html

`<input type="file" id="file" webkitdirectory (click)="resetFileValue($event)" (change)="selectFile($event)" >`

uploaddata.component.ts

`resetFileValue(event): any {`

`event.target.value = null;`

`this.eventValue = event;`

`}`

`selectFile(event: any): any {`

`this.showUploadModal = true;`

`this.uploadModal = {`

`display: 'block',`

`header: 'Add new User',`

`content: ' ',`

`okButton: 'Save',`

`cancelButton: 'Cancel',`

`submitFunction: () => { },`

`closeFunction: () => {`
`this.closeModalDialog();`
`},`

`data: event.target.files,`

`};`

`}`

Is there a way I can detect if a user selects a directory that contains no files at all so I can display a warning to the user?

Comment: after selecting directory are you able to see what data coming in event. Can you show the output of console what is coming when you select empty directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this with ng2-uploader. If Folder is empty then it work with drag and drop but not with webkitDirectory select  folder ethod.

```
<input #folderUpload type="file" (change)="onFolderAdd(folderUpload.files)" webkitDirectory ng2FileSelect/>
```